# Download por javascript não funciona no intel xdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, intel-xdk

Tenho um script que funciona normalmente no browser do celular e no browser do computador, porém quando gero um apk ele salva um arquivo com outra extensão ao invés da proposta.

Segue abaixo o meu script

```html
$("#download").click(function() {
  html2canvas($("#layout"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
   a.download = 'sou-enfermagem.jpeg';
   a.click();
    }
  });
 });
```

Só preciso que essa imagem seja salva na pasta download do android.
O que eu preciso alterar neste script para que funcione no android?